# Row down - Java script

Tags: row

I got this code: Right now the "item.movie" appear right after the "item.time" and "-" sign. I want the "item.movie" to show on a different row below the "item.time". I would love to get some help how can it be done. Thanks a lot.

```
var column = document.createElement('td');
        column.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.time + " - " + item.movie));
        row.appendChild(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
column.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.time + " - " + item.movie));
```

with

```
column.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.movie));
column.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
var timeEl = document.createTextNode(item.time);
timeEl.className = "movieTime";
column.appendChild(timeEl);
```

And add the css

```
.movieTime {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Hey - Thanks a lot! This is great!!! One more question please - How can i make the "item.time" text bold with underline? Maybe in CSS? Here is the full coed if needed https://jsfiddle.net/2y5bkv4a/3/

Comment: Hey. Can you please tell me where to place it in the code? jsfiddle.net/2y5bkv4a/3 Thanks

Comment: I could not load the jsfiddle.  I just see "Loading..." .  However, see the edits to my original post

Comment: Hey. I did those changes and no change. Maybe i have placed the CSS in a wrong place? Can you please check what i did in the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/2y5bkv4a/4/? Also - In order to load it you will need this JS file sendspace.com/file/vr706a - Sorry for the Hebrew Fonts :) Really appriciate your help

Comment: Hey - Can you please send me the updated fiddle link? I cannot find the updated one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I am still getting used to the jsfiddle workflow, I Updated but did not Set as Base.  Here is a fork with the correct code https://jsfiddle.net/mcmohorn/ehgv92b1/